# Cutting down on Stanford parser's time-to-parse by pruning the sentence

Tags: parsing, nlp, text-processing, text-parsing, text-analysis

We are already aware that the parsing time of Stanford Parser increases as the length of a sentence increases. I am interested in finding creative ways in which we prune the sentence such that the parsing time decreases without compromising on accuracy. For e.g. we can replace known noun phrases with one word nouns. Similarly can there be some other smart ways of guessing a subtree before hand, let's say, using the POS Tag information? We have a huge corpus of unstructured text at our disposal. So we wish to learn some common patterns that can ultimately reduce the parsing time. Also some references to publicly available literature in this regards will also be highly appreciated.

P.S. We already are aware of how to multi-thread using Stanford Parser, so we are not looking for answers from that point of view.

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to get out. What are you willing to lose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked for 'creative' approaches - the *Cell Closure* pruning method might be worth a look. See the series of publications by Brian Roark, Kristy Hollingshead, and Nathan Bodenstab. Papers: [1](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology-new/C/C08/C08-1094.pdf) [2](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology-new/N/N09/N09-1073.pdf) [3](http://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/abs/10.1162/COLI_a_00109). The basic intuition is:

- Each cell in the CYK parse chart 'covers' a certain span (e.g. the first 4 words of the sentence, or words 13-18, etc.)
- Some words - particularly in certain contexts - are *very* unlikely to begin a multi-word syntactic constituent; others are similarly unlikely to end a constituent. For example, the word 'the' almost always precedes a noun phrase, and it's almost inconceivable that it would end a constituent.
- If we can train a machine-learned classifier to identify such words with very high precision, we can thereby identify cells which would only participate in parses placing said words in highly improbable syntactic positions. (Note that this classifier might make use of a linear-time POS tagger, or other high-speed preprocessing steps.)
- By 'closing' these cells, we can reduce both the the asymptotic and average-case complexities considerably - in theory, from cubic complexity all the way to linear; practically, we can achieve approximately n^1.5 without loss of accuracy.

In many cases, this pruning actually *increases* accuracy slightly vs. an exhaustive search, because the classifier can incorporate information that isn't available to the PCFG. Note that this is a simple, but very effective form of coarse-to-fine pruning, with a single coarse stage (as compared to the 7-stage CTF approach in the Berkeley Parser).

To my knowledge, the Stanford Parser doesn't currently implement this pruning technique; I suspect you'd find it quite effective.

**Shameless plug**
The [BUBS Parser](http://bubs-parser.googlecode.com/) implements this approach, as well as a few other optimizations, and thus achieves throughput of around 2500-5000 words per second, usually with accuracy at least equal to that I've measured with the Stanford Parser. Obviously, if you're using the rest of the Stanford pipeline, the built-in parser is already well integrated and convenient. But if you need improved speed, BUBS might be worth a look, and it does include some example code to aid in embedding the engine in a larger system.

**Memoizing Common Substrings**
Regarding your thoughts on pre-analyzing known noun phrases or other frequently-observed sequences with consistent structure: I did some evaluation of a similar idea a few years ago (in the context of sharing common substructures across a large corpus, when parsing on a massively parallel architecture). The preliminary results weren't encouraging.In the corpora we looked at, there just weren't enough repeated substrings of substantial length to make it worthwhile. And the aforementioned cell closure methods usually make those substrings really cheap to parse anyway.

However, if your target domains involved a lot of repetition, you might come to a different conclusion (maybe it would be effective on legal documents with lots of copy-and-paste boilerplate? Or news stories that are repeated from various sources or re-published with edits?)